# Why do I always get the same error message in my ARIMA model script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, model, arima, python-3.9

Well I have to create ARIMA model for U.S GDP forecasting. However, even though I fixed almost every line I still get the same error message and I have got no idea what is wrong. 2 version of the script and error message: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s8DdF_jANqtq6EFlUKgOykv6bpQ_4deUx13LvDIRCrk/edit?usp=sharing